# error APT0000: invalid resource directory name: obj\Debug\dir with spaces "dir with spaces". Xamrin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im new to xamrin just looking around but didn't find the solution for b/m error

> invalid resource directory name: D:\Driod\obj\Debug-Development\60\res
>   resources-fvw "res resources-fvw".

detail says

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1703,2):
>   error APT0000: invalid resource directory name:
>   D:\Droid\obj\Debug-Development\60\res resources-fvw "res
>   resources-fvw".

Im not sure where is the issue i think its about SDK for andriod
if so, how can i check which SDK i need to install or reinstall

Comment: Do you have a resource by the name `res resources-fvw`?

Comment: @G.hakim yes i have res folder and inside it i have resources-fvw folder these all are in obj folder

Comment: and in project I have Resources-FVW folder in root

Comment: I don't have folder name "res resources-fvw"

Comment: Can you upload an image of all the folders you are currently having in your `Resource` folder, just use the snipping tool to snip it and upload it somewhere

Comment: delete obj folder manually and rebuild. if problem doesn't solved you probably have some syntax or naming error (syntax error xml/axml files, or you have file(s) contains `-`, `space` or something like that, just recheck your files and try again). sometimes the error message doesn't point to actual error. you will see a lot.